# how to use array in CSH using awk command

Tags: csh

I am using CSH script and i am grepping the lines b/w two patterns. It is working if the line is normal i.e. no extra character but it find special characters like [] it is showing no match. I am able to get it in bash script but my requirement is in CSH script

```
 cat file
 level input
 ram input
 rom input
 design input
 work input

 cat file 2
 level input
 acc_comp[0] input
 acc_comp[1] input
 pin[0] output
 work input
```

Expected result:
array = (ram rom design)

I have tried below command

```
         set array = (`awk '/level/{flag=1; next} /work/{flag=0} flag' file`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` command works fine; what is probably happening is:

```
% set array = ( `awk '/level/{flag=1; next} /work/{flag=0} flag' file2` )
% echo $array
echo: No match.
```

You need to add quotes around the variable to prevent any characters from being interpreted by the shell as glob characters:

```
% echo "$array"
acc_comp[0] input acc_comp[1] input pin[0] output
```

Your `awk` command prints the full line, so it's probably not exactly what you want; you want  `flag {print $1}` instead of just `flag` (which implies `print $0`):

```
% set array = ( `awk '/level/{flag=1; next} /work/{flag=0} flag {print $1}' file2` )
% echo "$array"
acc_comp[0] acc_comp[1] pin[0]
```